# Calling a WCF service with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, cross-domain

I created a WCF service with a method declared as follows

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="getDashBoard", Method="POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
getDashBoard object (string strGroups);
```

which returns a

```
List<Dictionary String, Object> rows = new List<Dictionary String, Object>();
```

serialized by JavaScriptSerializer

```
serializer.Serialize ( rows) ;
```

client-side i call the webservice method in this way

```
$.ajax ({
    type: " POST" ,
    url: url ,
    headers : {" Access -Control- Allow- Origin" , " *", " Access -Control- Request- Method" , " POST "},
    dataType : " json " ,
    contentType : "application / json ; charset = utf -8" ,
    date : ' {" strGroups ": " ISPB "} ' ,
    success : function ( data) {
        var content = JSON.parse ( data);
        $.each(content, function(i, item) {
            console.log(i) ;
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(" getDashBoard " + textStatus) ;
    }
});
```

with Firefox the call to the WS returns this error " NetworkError : 405 Method Not Allowed . Locked request multiorigine (cross- origin) : the criterion of the origin does not allow the reading of the remote resource http:// .... You can solve the problem ... by moving the resource on the same domain or activating CORS . "

with the debugger IE return data appear correctly formatted and the object "content" has all the correct values ​​; but the cycle doesn't work: it returns "Character is not valid"

help meeeeee !
i'm desperate :o

Thanks Cinzia

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$.ajax ({
type: " POST" ,
url: url ,
crossDomain : true,
dataType : " json " ,
date : ' {" strGroups ": " ISPB "} ' ,
success : function ( data) {
    var content = JSON.parse ( data);
    $.each(content, function(i, item) {
        console.log(i) ;
    });
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(" getDashBoard " + textStatus) ;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You must activate `CORS` on your WCF Service on the server-site. CORS is used to get arround the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy). [Here](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html) is a good resource about this.

Basically you first have to add a message inspector and later on you have to add the CORS-Heder to the response:

```
requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");

endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomHeaderMessageInspector(requiredHeaders));
```

The differed behavior in IE and FF comes from the preflighted `OPTIONS` call from FF ([description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)). If you enable CORS on your WCF-Service (like descried above), it should work in both browsers.

As an alternative you can run your service call on the same domain, but this depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer.
The problem is that even if i work on the SAME DOMAIN i have the same error "SCRIPT1014: Invalid character" on

```
$.each(content, function(i, item) {
        console.log(i) ;
    });
```

if i delete the rows code about the cycle, IE shows me the data return as below:

[{"Descr":"Altro","percValore":0.003},{"Descr":"altro 2","percValore":0.100}]

it seems correct!!! FireFox doesn't show nothing!
Maybe the problem is not the cross domain but the response?
Thank you Cinzia